# WPF text entrance and exit transition effects

Tags: c#, wpf, transition, effects

I want to create a WPF program with some nice effects (especially enterance and exit effects) for some text inside application.

I know [transitionals](http://transitionals.codeplex.com/) library, but it doesn't have professional effects! (and some professional ones in that library are slow and laggy...)

Actually, I want some effects like effects in `Microsoft Powerpoint 2010`...

Is there any library or something to have such effects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - there are several pixel shader style effects libraries. WPFFx is probably the most widely known one at  http://wpffx.codeplex.com/.

Note: the site says "This requires .NET framework 3.5 SP1 and requires Direct X SDK at compile time.. (to build the PS files)."  You will need to verify it works if you are running a later version of .NET.

Comment: It seems to be not easy to use :) Isn't there any other libraries? (I know `Transitionals` but its animations are too laggy, I think it's not hardware accelerated)